# Edit site_url with filter

Tags: wordpress, filter

With WordPress, calling `site_url()` returns the full site URL (`http://www.example.com`)
What I'm trying to do is adding something (`add-something-here`) at the end of the URL with filter.

The result I'm expecting is:
`http://www.example.com/add-something-here`

Does someone know how to do that with filter?

I tried the following with no success:

```
function custom_site_url($url) {
    return get_site_url('/add-something-here');
}
add_filter('site_url', 'custom_site_url');
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are producing a loop with this filter. The function `get_site_url` is exactly where the filter `site_url` is being called.

You need:

```
add_filter( 'site_url', 'custom_site_url' );

function custom_site_url( $url )
{
    if( is_admin() ) // you probably don't want this in admin side
        return $url;

    return $url .'/something';
}
```

Bear in mind, that this may produce errors for scripts that rely on the real URL.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but since it's PHP could you just try...

```
function custom_site_url($url) {
    return get_site_url() . '/add-something-here';
}
add_filter('site_url', 'custom_site_url');
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this is a snippet of what I use often:

```
$constant = 'add-something-here';
return '<a href="'. esc_url(site_url().'/'.$constant.'/'">'. esc_html( $name ).'</a>';
```

or you might simply want to get the page ID instead and it's much better.

```
 $page_id = '2014';
 return  <a href="'. get_page_link ($page_id) .'">'.esc_html__( 'pagename', 'text-domain' ).'</a>
```