# Development workflow for Wordpress using git - need to override get_bloginfo('wpurl')

Tags: git, wordpress

I'm going with [this git workflow](http://davidwinter.me/articles/2012/04/09/install-and-manage-wordpress-with-git/) for my current wordpress project which I'm running locally using `MAMP`. It allows me to separate the WP core files from the theme and plugin folders using submodules, which is great. My `wp-config` has some extra entries to tell Wordpress where the core files are and where the theme folders are:

```
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wordpress/');

define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/core');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/core/wordpress');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', realpath(ABSPATH . '../wp-content/'));
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_HOME . '/wp-content');
define('UPLOADS', '../wp-content/uploads');
```

My structure from the site root looks like:

```
-wordpress (contains core files)
-wp-content
    -themes
    -plugins
    -uploads
-wp-config.php
```

So my home url is: `http://localhost:8888/core/`

The issues I'm running into all over is with the plugins. Some of them are using `get_bloginfo('wpurl')` to load assets. So an example of that would look like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/core/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/{PLUGIN}/images/{PLUGIN_IMAGE}.png
```

where it should actually be:

```
http://localhost:8888/core/wp-content/plugins/{PLUGIN}/images/{PLUGIN_IMAGE}.png
```

Can I override this somehow without modifying the plugins individually?

**UPDATE**

This works but I need to limit it only to when plugins are called:

```
function alter_site_url($url) {
    return str_replace('/core/wordpress', '/core', $url);
}

add_filter('site_url', 'alter_site_url');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_bloginfo('wpurl')`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/general-template.php#L400) calls [`site_url()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1928) behind the scenes, which in turn calls [`get_site_url()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1948).  [`get_site_url()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1948) has a filter, `site_url`, that you could use to change the value returned by the function.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455569/edit-site-url-with-filter/15455954#15455954) has an example of how you could add it.  Bear in mind that that would change it globally, and could cause other problems (things that are currently working could start breaking).

Comment: See the update to my question. I need to only do this when plugins are calling `get_bloginfo('wpurl')` and I have no idea how to limit the filter to do just that. Otherwise yeah like you said, it breaks the site.

Comment: Hmm; it's pretty ugly, and I'm not certain of all the implications, but perhaps in your filter you could check the call stack (eg with [debug-backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) ) to see if any of the functions are called from files are in the `plugins` directory.  Seems pretty ugly though.

Comment: Yeah i'm not gonna do that. Very ugly. I guess I'll just update the plugins, ugh. Thanks