# WordPress get_bloginfo() ignoring WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL constants

Tags: wordpress

In the database, `siteurl` and `home` is set to `http://incorrecturl.local`

I've defined both the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants like so:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://correct.local');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://correct.local');
```

But it's ignored, and instead the database value is output instead:

```
get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url') //=> http://incorrecturl.local/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.css
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how wordpress build these urls internally. I think that those constants aren't use in the function you called beacuse it's not able to overwrite constants:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://correct.local');
define('WP_HOME','http://incorrect.local');
echo WP_HOME;
```

This will result in a PHP_NOTICE that WP_HOME is already defined, so it prints http://correct.local.

But for WP_HOME there is a filter to change the home_url: http://de.wpseek.com/hook/home_url/ There is also one for the siteurl: [Edit site_url with filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455569/edit-site-url-with-filter) By using these filters you should be able to change both urls as you want.

Comment: This is frustrating - I need to be able to change the URL on a site-by-site basis, not on a plugin/theme basis. I think you may have also misunderstood - the constant definitions are in `wp-config.php` and the `get_bloginfo()` function call is in the themes.